# How do you translateX by x amount relative to it's position in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a carousel component in React and I'm having trouble implementing the next, and previous functionality:

```
  const onClickPrevious = () => {
    const box = opstionsListRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    opstionsListRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${box.x - 300}px)`;
  };

  const onClickNext = () => {
    const box = opstionsListRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    opstionsListRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${box.x + 100}px)`;
  };
```

I had to decrement by 300 just to have a more decent translateX, but it still not working 100% correctly.

Comment: you might wanna add a transition to it. What do you mean when you say it's "not working 100%"?  It's not moving or its jumpy or something else?

Comment: In principle your code should work. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: You should *never* update a ref in react if you can do so normally. It will be canceled on next update.

Comment: @mousetail here he is not updating a ref but rather updating the value that is stored in the ref. There should be no issues with that.

Comment: Yes there is, you can easily update the style normally, which would avoid many bugs

Comment: I don't follow. Ref's are useful for many scenarios where you want access to a component on a different level in the tree (where changing the style would not be as natural and more of a hassle another way). What type of bugs are you talking about when you mention that? I'm curious.

Comment: A re-render can clear the custom attributes you set

Comment: it cannot unless you would change the attributes in the render portion of the component. here they are nested in arrow functions which will be recreated on every render, yes, but that does not mean the values will be reset on every render. Those are probably tied to a onClick event, which means it will only be called on an actual click, not during rendering. Here a sandbox for illustration. https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-sea-fqpvo0?file=/src/App.js Click on the h2, then change the state. the style will stay the same.